# pandas convert objects with numbers and nans to ints or floats

Tags: pandas, dataframe, object, floating-point, int

with the knowledge that similar cases have been answered several times I couldn't make it work anyway.

sample data:

```
10
5
20

5

6
```

after i figured out that with:

```
df = df['column_name'].astype(str).astype(int)
```

it would work if there wasn't nans in the input data.

```
error: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'nan'
```

Also I did try to use float instead but it gives an error as well

```
error: could not convert string to float
```

what am I missing?

output can be anything with "null", "nan", "" for example:

```
10
5
20
null
5
null
6
```

Comment: have you tried `pd.to_numeric(df['column_name'])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert to numeric with [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) and `errors='coerce'` for floats in columns and for integers use [`nullable integer data type`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html) (pandas 0.24+):

```
df['column_name'] = pd.to_numeric(df['column_name'], errors='coerce').astype('Int64')
print (df)
   column_name
0           10
1            5
2           20
3          NaN
4            5
5          NaN
6            6
```

**Detail**:

```
print (pd.to_numeric(df['column_name'], errors='coerce'))
0    10.0
1     5.0
2    20.0
3     NaN
4     5.0
5     NaN
6     6.0
Name: column_name, dtype: float64
```

Comment: wow, that was quick. just one little question to your answer: to_numeric gives me "" instead of NaN as you wrote in your example. Normal behaviour or do i produce another error?

Comment: @J.Doe - Do you think if write to file? How is tested it?

Comment: yes if i write to_excel in the excel all the cells with no value are empty no NaN nor null ;)

Comment: @J.Doe - Reason is `to_excel` replace missing values to empty values.

Comment: Thank you so much! live saver =) there are so many answers which doesn't really get you to the point