# Convert floats to ints of a column with numbers and nans

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm working with Python 3.6 and Pandas 1.0.3.

I would like to convert the floats from column "A" to int... This column has some nan values.

So i followed this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57656860/pandas-convert-objects-with-numbers-and-nans-to-ints-or-floats) with the solution of @jezrael.

But I get the following error:
"TypeError: cannot safely cast non-equivalent float64 to int64"

This is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'timestamp': [1588757760.0000, 1588757760.0161, 1588757764.7339, 1588757764.9234], 'A':[9087.6000, 9135.8000, np.nan, 9102.1000], 'B':[0.1648, 0.1649, '', 5.3379], 'C':['b', 'a', '', 'a']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['A'] = pd.to_numeric(df['A'], errors='coerce').astype('Int64')
print(df)
```

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you have *true* float numbers, not integers in the float form. So for safety reasons pandas will not convert them, because you would be obtained **other** values.

So you need first *explicitely round them to integers,* and only then use the`.astype()` method:

```
df['A'] = pd.to_numeric(df['A'].round(), errors='coerce').astype('Int64')
```

---

Test:

```
print(df)
```

> ```
>       timestamp     A       B  C
> 0  1.588758e+09  9088  0.1648  b
> 1  1.588758e+09  9136  0.1649  a
> 2  1.588758e+09   NaN           
> 3  1.588758e+09  9102  5.3379  a
> ```

Comment: Thanks @MarianD. This solution seems to give the same result as that of "NYC Coder". The value "nan" is converted to "<NA>". Is it possible to convert this value to 'nan' as originally? I will update my post to explain the result I get with your solution

Comment: @David, no. `nan` is of data type `float64` and all data in a column must be of the same data type; `Int64` data type with NaN values is experimental and may be dropped in future versions of pandas.

Comment: Effectively. Thank you for that clarification. Your answer is very good as well, it's the "<NA>" that I get are simply not annoying because I can treat them as empty data. Thank you very much @MarianD !

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to convert NaN to a integer:

```
df['A'] = df['A'].fillna(99999999).astype(np.int64, errors='ignore')
df['A'] = df['A'].replace(99999999, np.nan)
df

    timestamp   A   B   C
0   1.588758e+09    9087    0.1648  b
1   1.588758e+09    9135    0.1649  a
2   1.588758e+09    NaN     
3   1.588758e+09    9102    5.3379  a
```

Comment: df['A'] = df['A'].astype(np.int64, errors='ignore')

Comment: That won't change it to an integer. This will ignore all errors including the float to int conversion error.

Comment: Yes indeed. I want to keep the values 'nan'.

Comment: Check the edited answer. Unfortunately there isn't a good way to do this.

Comment: Thanks @NYC Coder, I just checked. But it doesn't seem to work except by changing the following line ```df['A'] = df['A'].fillna(99999999).astype(np.int64, errors='ignore')``` by ```df['A'] = df['A'].fillna(99999999).astype(np.int64, errors='ignore').astype('Int64')``` but is not perfect because nan value has been converted to <NA>

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing. The 2 steps i gave above should work. The second `.astype('Int64')`is not required.

Comment: In fact, I get this output without the second ```.astype('Int64')```
```
      timestamp       A       B  C
0  1.588758e+09  9087.0  0.1648  b
1  1.588758e+09  9135.0  0.1649  a
2  1.588758e+09     NaN           
3  1.588758e+09  9102.0  5.3379  a
```