# How can I resolve - TypeError: cannot safely cast non-equivalent float64 to int64?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to convert a few float columns to int in a DF but I'm getting above error.  I've tried both to convert it as well as to fillna to 0(which I prefer not to do, as in my dataset the NA is required).

What am I doing wrong?
I've tried both:

```
orginalData[NumericColumns] = orginalData[NumericColumns].astype('Int64')
#orginalData[NumericColumns] = orginalData[NumericColumns].fillna(0).astype('Int64')
```

but it keeps resulting in the same error

```
TypeError: cannot safely cast non-equivalent float64 to int64
```

What can I do to convert the columns?

Comment: Does this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61712916/convert-floats-to-ints-of-a-column-with-numbers-and-nans) help?

Comment: @BalajiAmbresh Thank you, I tried it and got a different error - TypeError: arg must be a list, tuple, 1-d array, or Series

Comment: Could try for 1 numeric column at a time instead of all numeric columns in 1 shot?

Comment: @BalajiAmbresh yes, it worked for one item but not for the list of columns

Comment: you may have to use `.apply` for a list of columns

Comment: @anky I'm not familiar how to do that?

Comment: What `pandas` version are you using?

Comment: @nimbous I'm using - 1.0.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
orginalData[NumericColumns] = orginalData[NumericColumns].fillna(0).astype(np.int64, errors='ignore')
```

For NaNs you need to replace the NaNs with 0, then do the type casting

Comment: no luck. I ran it..no errors(as we are ignoring it) but when I check the column type it's still all float64

Comment: when I remove the ignore errors flag I get - Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer

Comment: I think you need to `df.fillna(0)` and then do the casting

Comment: The only situation in which this would be correct is if NaN is interchangeable with zero. In many cases there is no appropriate integer substitute for NaN.

Comment: Not acceptable if it is not acceptable to replace NaN with 0.

Answer (score 33):

**No need to replace** `nan`.
You can pass to `Int64` **safely** by doing:

```
df['A'] = np.floor(pd.to_numeric(df['A'], errors='coerce')).astype('Int64')
```

Your `nans` will be replaced with `<NA>`.
[Source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/37429)

You need to have pandas >.24 version.

Comment: Perfect solution, Thank you, I tried all other solutions and none served my purpose.

Comment: I still get the same error 'cannot safely cast non-equivalent float64 to int64'. I really hate this in pandas - that you can't use integers if there are any null values...

Comment: As the above comment,
```pd.to_numeric(df[col], errors='coerce').astype('Int64')```

yielded me the same error, but 
```pd.to_numeric(df[col], errors='coerce').astype(int)```

worked, and it turns out the dtype is `Int64`, so that works fine.
But is it supposed to ? Why is there an implicit cast to Int64 when the explicit (ie more pythonic) cast fails ?

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for a robust solution like this for a long time, in my case I needed to have NaN to export the data with blank fields, so I add a .replace("<NA>",np.NaN) and works good too

Answer (score 1):

The accepted solution is not correct in all cases, re: "np.floor".  From the documentation at:
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.floor.html

"The floor of the scalar x is the largest integer i, such that i <= x. It is often denoted as [x]."

This will turn 9.99 to 9.00, and any downstream calculations will be inaccurate relative to the original data set.

Answer (score -1):

Array must only contain whole numbers in order to safely convert float to int dtype. If you insist you can try as below:

```
orginalData[NumericColumns] = orginalData[NumericColumns].astype(int, errors='ignore')
```

As per your pandas version you can safely convert multiple columns at once. You don't need to use apply for this.

Comment: I do not think this works. I tried this - orginalData[NumericColumns] = orginalData[NumericColumns].astype(int, errors='ignore')

for item in orginalData[NumericColumns].dtypes:
    print(item)

all I got is a list of float64

Comment: format looks bad. Basically I rant your command then did a loop of the type and it's still all floats.

Comment: when I remove the ignore errors flag I get - Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer

Comment: @Lostsoul Fair enough, the other option is to `round` and then attempt convert dtype: `orginalData[NumericColumns].round(0).astype(int, errors='ignore')` You may change 0 to specify the number of decimal places to round each column to as per your use case though. Also chain `replace` before or after `round` to replace `np.inf` and `np.nan` to see if that works.

Comment: When I do that, I get ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer. (I am removing the ignore errors flag because it doesn't give a error but doesn't actually do anything)